# Is this the correct approach for fitting a lognormal distribution with known population mean to given data?

Tags: lognormal-distribution

I have some incomplete data for loss ratios (=loss/revenue) for 5 years. Let's call it X. Suppose these are the given values for X:

2012 - 73%;
2013 - 67%;
2014 - 78%;
2015 - 81%;
2016 - 75%;

I was also provided with a best estimate of the mean of the data of 83% (Note: This is not just the average of the above figures, it includes some other factors which I am not aware of).

I want to fit a lognormal distribution to this data. These are the steps I followed, and I want to know if this is an appropriate estimation:

1. Assume that E[X]=83%
2. Estimate σ using MLE. i.e the standard deviation of ln(X_i's)
3. Use the formula E[X] = exp(μ+σ^2/2), with E[X] = 83% and σ from step 2, to solve for an estimate of μ

So, I get X ~ Lognormal(μ,σ) and E[X] = 83%.

I want to know if this an appropriate method to fit a lognormal distribution to this data?

I know technically I should be using μ = Average(ln(X_i's)) to estimate μ, but I want to assume that 83% is the best estimate of the mean, and then reflect the standard deviation from the given data.

Comment: Hi LilStats, welcome to Cross Validated. Are you sure want to fit a log-normal? It looks like you have percentages, which are limited between (0,1) or (0, 100). Log-normal is defined between (0, infinity), and is often very skewed. It might be more suitable to use something like a beta distribution.

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for your reply. Although they are percentages, the X's can range from (0, inf), and I am looking for a distribution that is right-skewed. With that being said, my concern is not whether log-normal distribution is the right fit, but whether my method of estimating the lognormal parameters is appropriate.

Comment: it doesnt sound 'correct', you are mixing sample and population mean. i would have thought you would need to solve mle directly for the ln(x_i) substituting for mu using the constraint ln .83=mu+.5\sigma^2

Answer (score 0):

Your $X_i= \exp(\mu +\sigma \epsilon_i)$ with epsilon standard normal.

You assume the population mean is
$$0.83=\exp(\mu + 1/2 \sigma^2)$$

So dividing all the $X_i$ by 83%,
$$X_i/0.83=Z_i=\exp(- 1/2 \sigma^2 +\sigma \epsilon_i) $$

So here, I would want to confirm what the MLE for $\sigma$, given data

$$\ln Z_i \sim N(- 1/2 \sigma^2 ,\sigma^2 )$$

what I was hoping is that you could simply slot in the formula for the variance of a lognormal distribution and match the sample variance to the population variance

$$Var(Z_i) = (\exp(\sigma^2)-1)$$